# GLTFLoader does not allow to replace its default materials

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I have the following scene.

`AmbientLight` color: light blue

`PointLight` color: pink

a loaded gltf object with textures

I loaded a gltf object with texture map using `GLTFLoader`, the model is correctly loaded with textures using `MeshStandardMaterial` by default in picture 1. Now I want to change all the `MeshStandardMaterial` to `MeshPhongMaterial`, the way I am doing it is just loop through all the meshes, and update the material,for example:

```
// find gltf scene
var gltfScene = scene.children.find(ele => ele.type === 'Scene');    
var meshes = gltfScene.children;
for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
  // for each mesh, change to MeshPhongMaterial
  meshes[i].material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()
}
```

however, after I do that, all the mesh color turn to flat color of my `AmbientLight` color, and they do **NOT** reacts to light anymore (`SpotLight`, `PointLight`) in picture 2, you can see the pink from `PointLight` is gone.

Could anyone please help on why and how I can replace with `MeshPhongMaterial`.

here is the codepen https://codepen.io/chen-xu/pen/XWJWbwj, the problem happens if you click on `Replace Horse Mesh`, you will see the pink light is gone.

[image: default loaded object with MeshStandardMaterial]

[image: I change the material to MeshPhongMaterial]

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are not traversing through the `glTF` scene correctly. It should look like so:

```js
gltf.scene.traverse( ( child ) => { 

    if ( child.isMesh ) {

        child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    }

} );
```

`three.js R111`

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it, it still does not work, the object still turned into AmbientLight color, and all meshes do not react to lights.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Mugen87, this answer is also from you on Github, we need to add `{flatShading: true}`

```
gltf.scene.traverse( ( child ) => { 

    if ( child.isMesh ) {

        child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({flatShading: true});

    }

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a couple of extra steps to get it to work for me, also with gltf.

```js
gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {

        if (child.isMesh) {

          const originalMaterial = child.material;
          const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

          // these are missing and required
          child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
          // use the texture from the original material
          newMaterial.map = originalMaterial.map;

          child.material = newMaterial;
      }
})
```

note: `flatShading = true` sort of works but won't give you the smoother interpolated shading most people probably want.